# Selecting Specific file using uigetfile in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

i am doing small `matlab` code  where have to open a directory and then select image from there , the selected image has to be stored in a variable I  i have  loaded directory  using

```
  [mat, dirc] = uigetfile('*.png', 'Select a  file');
```

image is loaded loaded  in matlab   like this

[image]

i want "selected image to be saved in  a variable".
Please help me to do it .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diplaying Contents of Directory in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596911/diplaying-contents-of-directory-in-matlab)

Comment: @Shai Well, that question has been marked as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the image file

```
img = imread( fullfile(dirc, mat) );
```